# angularjs whatsapp sharing link does not show the og tag values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, seo, prerender

We have issue in sharing link in WhatsApp, it is ignoring _escaped_fragment_ , In our angularjs app we have following url

```
http://host_name/!#/user/1
```

all the bot facebook google twitter linked is converting this to

```
http://host_name/?_escaped_fragment_=/user/1
```

Everything is working fine. The issue with WhatsApp bot, which is ignoring,

Our htaccess rule is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet|LinkedInBot|bingbot|Yahoo|MSNBot|YahooSeeker|baiduspider|rogerbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|Slackbot|Slack-ImgProxy|Slackbot-LinkExpanding|Site\ Analyzer|SiteAnalyzerBot|Viber|Whatsapp|Telegram)
RewriteRule ^$ /SEO/static-page.php [R,NC,L]
```

Please let us know if any one has information or faced similar issue

Comment: Try changing "Whatsapp" to "WhatsApp" in your user agent check. You might have issues though since you are using the #!. If they don't change the URL to add the `?_escaped_fragment_=` query parameter, then you might not see the full URL being accessed. I'd suggest switching to html5 push state if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Yes we changed it to  WhatsApp user agent, Now the the control is going to php but we are not able to get the parameters from the url, is it changing to html5 push state is only the option, because we have working everything all the bot facebook, google bot, only we are having issue with whatsapp

Comment: I think so. Facebook will change #! URLs to ?_escaped_fragment_= and so will Google. If WhatsApp doesn't, then your server will only ever see the URL before the #.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsin. you save my lots of time...